# Migrating ServiceNow Users into Azure AAD

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, migration, servicenow

I have integrated Azure into our ServiceNow portal and we also migrated the Azure users into ServiceNow, which works fine,
But now I also want to do the other way around, to migrate exisiting users from ServiceNow into Azure.
Is there any way to do this without doing this manually? I know there is the option of exporting the users from servicenow, but how can I import them directly into Azure?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to automate this process by first requesting all users via ServiceNow-API and then use az-cli command palette to check which of your users' e-mail addresses already exist in your AAD.

You can then also use az-cli to create new users in your AAD based on the information you gathered from your ServiceNow instance.

This process would be idempotent and reusable in a scheduled way.